# How to read screen EDID data?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to parse screen EDID info. Unfortunately, it's not any of usual encoding data. 
Do you happen to know how to transform data in 'IODisplayEDID' to something readable? Maybe 'Dictionary'?

Here is my code:

```
    var object : io_object_t
    var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
    let matching = IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect")

    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                  matching,
                                                  &serialPortIterator)
    if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult && serialPortIterator != 0 {
        repeat {
            object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
            let info = IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary(object, UInt32(kIODisplayOnlyPreferredName)).takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary as! [String:AnyObject]

            if let displayEDID = info["IODisplayEDID"] as? Data {

                print(displayEDID) // <-- How do I parse this data correctly?
            }

        } while object != 0
    }
    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
```

Comment: That's a data structure, it's just bytes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data And it's quite convoluted. There's this [C program](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/edid-decode/) which parses a lot of things. This is a very complex structure.

Comment: Thanks, @EricAya with the help of wiki you provided I wrote the code which extracts the data I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so basically I used the wiki reference Eric Aya provided in the comments. I read the 8-9 bytes in specified order to extract the tree numbers of the alphabet letters. On my mac the results read "APP" which I guess means that manufacturer is Apple.

```
            if let displayEDID = info["IODisplayEDID"] as? Data {

                let array = Array(displayEDID)

                var bits : UInt16 = UInt16(array[8])
                bits = bits << 8  + UInt16(array[9])

                let thirdLetterIndex = Int(bits & 31)
                let secondLetterIndex = Int(bits >> 5 & 31)
                let firsLetterIndex = Int(bits >> 10 & 31)


                let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters.flatMap { $0.description }
                let manufactorer = chars[firsLetterIndex - 1] + chars[secondLetterIndex - 1] + chars[thirdLetterIndex - 1]


                print(manufactorer) // Result for my mac is "APP"
            }
```