# How can I identify different displays in macOS?

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I tried `CGDisplaySerialNumber()`, but it seems like a lot of vendors just return the same number here. I'm looking for a way for my code to uniquely identify attached displays that will survive across reboots of both the displays and the Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You best tool you have is the [DisplayID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services). See particularly the section on "Finding Displays." For example, to get the main display's ID, use [CGMainDisplayID()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455620-cgmaindisplayid). To get all connected display IDs, use [CGGetOnlineDisplayList()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454964-cggetonlinedisplaylist).

The display ID is a combination of:

- Vendor
- Model
- Serial number
- Position in the I/O Kit registry

It should be persistent across reboots, though it may not be stable across re-configurations that modify the registry (I believe this can happen for certain changes to the graphics card settings, but I don't believe it's common). You can create your own mapping using vendor (CGDisplayVendorNumber), model (CGDisplayModelNumber), and serial number (CGDisplaySerialNumber).

As you note, not all vendors provide a unique serial number, so in some cases it may not be possible to track a monitor that was re-registered, and has exactly the same vendor, model, and serial number as another monitor connected to this machine.

You can explore fetching the underlying [EDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100439/how-to-read-screen-edid-data), which is going to be about as unique an identifier that exists and is where the other stuff generally comes from. But most of that is still going to be the same for two monitors of the same model. If the manufacturer doesn't bother with a serial number, they probably also don't bother with the "week of manufacturing" field, either, and probably just have the same EDID block for every monitor (that makes manufacturing cheaper and easier).

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a lot of confidence in the DisplayID. I notice when I print them out from my MacBook Pro with two LG monitors, the DisplayIDs are just 0, 1, and 2. On our client's MacPro, connected to two Teranex AV's, the DisplayID's do look a little more complex. I should do some more experiments. What we're seeing right now is that it's 50-50 which Teranex is on the left and which is on the right. We're considering getting EDID emulators that will let us edit the serial, or possibly something that will let us control the sequence the devices are powered on.